# How to add Template class as member within a normal class

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, c++14

I have a template class: `templClass` which takes in a type and works like a regular template class. I want that class to be a member of another regular class `regClass`. 
`regClass` has a member variable `var`, based on which I wish to create `templClass` of `type1` or `type2`:
So it is as follows

```
template <class T>
class templClass
{
  //constructor  
};

class regClass
{
public:
    regClass()
    {
        // constructor for other members
    }
    int var;
    templClass templClass_;
    // if (var == 0)
    // {I want templClass<type1>}
    // else
    // {I want templClass<type2>}
};
```

How can I achieve this? 
The implementation above throws a compiler error `error: invalid use of template-name 'templClass' without an argument list`

Comment: You can't do this.

Comment: Perhaps telling what you are looking to do would be better? Look like a strong case of [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible.

You'll have to use an explicit instantiation of the class template. E.g.

```
templClass<int> templClass_;
```

or

```
templClass<double> templClass_;
```

Another option is to make `regClass` also a class template where `var` is the template parameter instead of a member variable.

```
template <int> struct MemberTypeSelector;
template <> struct MemberTypeSelector<0>
{
   using type = templClass<int>;
};

template <> struct MemberTypeSelector<1>
{
   using type = templClass<double>;
};

// Add more specializations of MemberTypeSelector as needed.

template <int var>
class regClass
{
   public:

      using MemberType = typename MemberTypeSelector<var>::type;
      regClass()
      {
         // constructor for other members
      }

      MemberType member;
};
```

Comment: Or `std::variant<templClass<int>, templClass<double>> templClass_;` and then deal with packaging and unpackaging of the std::variant member variable.

Answer (score 0):

As @Eljay said in the comments, a proper solution would be to use a [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant):

```
using AnyTemplClass = std::variant<templClass<int>, templClass<double>>;

class regClass
{
public:
    regClass()
    {
        if (var == 0) {
            templClass_ = templClass<int>{};
        } else {
            templClass_ = templClass<double>{};
        } 
    }
    int var = 0;
    AnyTemplClass templClass_;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, if we remember that template is not an type, but rather name for family of possible types, it is than clear, that we can't declare data member with type which would be name of template. We need to explicitly define which type from whole family is the type of member. Cause, you obviously do not want to parameterize regClass by type or you will have template again, depending of the compiler you are using, solution could to use union or std::variant as type of member, but, than you need to specify all possible types in advance. I would prefer parameterizing of regClass by type T and than member type would be
tempClass< T >

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

Probably the simpliest way to explain this is the moment of instantiation. When you write:

```
regClass instance;
```

then the compiler is unable to deduce the `T` type of the embedded template `templClass<T>` class. `templClass` alone by itself is not a complete type.

Therefore you have two options:

1. Specify the type directly inside the `regClass` class definition:

```
    class regClass
    {
    public:
        regClass()
        {
            // constructor for other members
        }
        int var;
        templClass<int> templClass_;
        // [...]
    };
```

That way you can write `regClass instance;`, but the embedded object type will always be of type `templClass<int>`.

2. Make the external class a templated class:

```
    template <class T>
    class regClass
    {
    public:
        regClass()
        {
            // constructor for other members
        }
        int var;
        templClass<T> templClass_;
        // [...]
    };
```

This way you can decide the type at the moment of instantiation, e.g. `regClass<std::string> instance;`.